# Server event not fired after JQUERY validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to jquery, Please help me resolve the below issue.

I have a modal popup and inside the popup i have two asp buttons(Search and close). Onclick of the search button i want to perform a validation and then fire the server button click event and on click of the close button i want to close the dialog.

**Problems faced:**
1. Onclick of search the jquery validation is happening but the server side event is not getting fired.
2. Onclick of close, the dialog is getting closed only for the first time but after click of the search button once, the close JQUERY is not getting fired.

**Below is the code:**

***button to open dialog***

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenDialog" runat="server" Text="Change"/>
```

***jquery to open dialog***

```
$("[id*=btnOpenDialog]").live("click", function () {
$("#modal_dialog").dialog({
title: "Details",
modal: true,
width: "700px"              
});
return false;
})
```

***The dialog with the asp buttons***

```
<div id="modal_dialog" style="display:none">
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="true" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>                           

<asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" Width="100px"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"> </asp:Label>                            
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>   
<asp:Button ID ="btnClose" Text="Close" runat="server"></asp:Button>      

</div>
```

***The btnSearch JQUERY***

```
$("[id*=btnSearch]").live("click", function (e) {          
//e.preventDefault();
var firstName = $("#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>").val();
var lastName = $("#<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>").val();

if(firstName == "" & lastName == "")
{                          
$("#<%= lblError.ClientID %>").text("Enter minimum two characters in either first name or last name");              
return false;
}
else
{
$("#<%= lblError.ClientID %>").text("");
$("#hdnFirstNameInitiator").val($("#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>").val());
$("#hdnLastNameInitiator").val($("#<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>").val());  
return true;
}
})
```

***The close button JQUERY***

```
$("[id*=btnClose]").live("click", function (e) {
//e.preventDefault();              
$("#modal_dialog").dialog('close');
return true;
})
```

Also if possible please brief me about e.preventDefault() and appendTo functions in jquery.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the validation passing or failing?

Comment: @Skeen, The validation is working

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault will allow you change the default behavior the the element. for example a submit button will try to submit a form when click, a link to try to go to the href, an anchor tag will try to go to its anchor.  preventDefault will prevent that default behavior so you can control the action with jQuery and do other things.

This might be source to some of your problems because you are preventing the default behavior like a post or submit which web forms relys on.

Web forms and jquery don't always play nice.  The more you get into jQuery/client side the more you might want to move toward ASP.Net MVC.

With web forms I would also you static id `ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static` as jQuery will rely a lot in finding elements by ID and web forms will rename everything.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 : You are using UseSubmitBehavior="false" for your search button. This will not allow .net to use the regular server side event, in this case button click, to execute.

e.preventDefault() is used if you want to disable the regular functionality of a control, like hyperlink functionality of an anchor tag.